# «ФенОмен» или «феномЕн»?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно поставить ударение в слове *феномен*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ФенОмен фиксируется большинством словарей как нормативное.
При этом ряд современных словарей даёт феномЕн как допустимое или даже нормативное наряду с фенОмен.
Но тут есть сложность. У слова несколько значений, феномЕн возможно только для одного.
Вот как даёт это Кузнецов:

Большой толковый словарь
ФЕН'ОМЕН; ФЕНОМ'ЕН, -а; м. [от греч. phainomenon - являющееся]
1. только фенOмен.
Необычное, особенное явление, редкий факт. Ф. долголетия. Мода - социальный ф.
2. О человеке, отличающемся какими-л. выдающимися способностями, талантами, чертами и т.п. Он настоящий ф. Эта женщина - ф. энергии.
3. только фенОмен. В идеалистической философии:
познаваемое явление, принципиально отличное от якобы непознаваемой сущности предметов. < Феноменальный (см.).

Другими словами,
**Человек — фенОмен и феномЕн

Явление или факт — только фенОмен.**

Answer (score 2):

В справочнике "Словарь ударений для работников радио и телевидения" (2012) дается такое решение: фенОмен (1) и (разг.) феномЕн (2). У Резниченко (2009): фенОмен и феномЕн.

ФенОмен - слово греческого происхождения (являющееся; то, что является; явление), феномЕн - заимствовано из фр. языка в 18 веке с соответствующим ударением.

Феноменом мы называем нечто редкое или удивительное (явление, человека).

Изменение значения слова: явление - удивительное явление.

Answer (score -1):

ФеномЕн, по-моему. По правилам чтения древнегреческого языка, ударение ставилось на предпоследний слог. А так как в исходнике было феномЕнон, то и феномЕн.

Comment: Ошибаетесь, @strekoza74. Фено́мен (по греч. φαινόμενον — с ударением на втором слоге, «являющееся», «явление») — термин, в общем смысле означающий явление, данное в чувственном созерцании. В естественной науке под феноменом понимается наблюдаемое явление или событие. ФеномЕн - заимствовано из фр. языка в 18 веке с соответствующим ударением на последнем слоге. Является разговорным вариантом.